# How to display animated images in a ListView control

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, listview

How can I add an animated image (such as  GIF) into a ListView control in a Windows application?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about .NET (C# / VB.NET).  I don't think this is possible by default.  You can choose to implement one using owner drawn.  See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) for example.

Comment: Thankx Jimmy...I have got a link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListViewEmbeddedControls.aspx
I m trying this thing. But not able to display the animated images in column 0. It is always coming on header part..:(

Answer (score 0):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) (an open source wrapper around a standard ListView) can display animated GIFs (as well as doing lots of other more useful features). Have a look at the demo to see them in action.

There is also an [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) which describing this control.